# SQL Server auto generates triggers and blocks my CRUD operations on my web application

Tags: sql-server, triggers, signalr

I am facing a strange trigger issue in the last few weeks on my ASP.NET Core web application to add or update data which is stored on my local SQL Server. I only have tables and views on my database, no triggers, but when I try to add or update data via Linq method syntax queries, Visual Studio throws an error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: Could not save changes because the target table has database triggers. Please configure your entity type accordingly, see https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-sqlserver-save-changes-and-triggers for more information.
>
> SqlException: The target table 'tbl_Countries' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.

I found a solution to overcome of this. The solution is to declare Visual Studio that each table has triggers automatically generated by SQL Server.

```
builder.Entity<tbl_Countries>().ToTable(tb => tb.HasTrigger("tr_dbo_tbl_Countries_05f5745b-9b96-4d32-b09e-4be5651c2649_Sender"));
base.OnModelCreating(builder);
```

It worked fine at first, but SQL Server sometimes generate a new trigger i need to change trigger's name in Visual Studio again.
I don't have any idea why SQL Server automatically generates triggers and how to overcome of it. If I wait some time and refresh my table in database, the trigger disappears but automatically generating next time I try to add or update a data.

I am using SignalR to get real time data and cookie sessions on my web project.

I have also used `enable_broker` on SQL Server database due to dependency of SignalR:

```
alter database myProjectDB 
    set enable_broker with rollback immediate
```

Full error details on Visual Studio:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Could not save changes because the target table has database triggers. Please configure your entity type accordingly, see https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-sqlserver-save-changes-and-triggers for more information.
  Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Update.Internal.SqlServerModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at myProject.Controllers.AdminController.CountryAdd(tbl_Countries cnt) in C:\myProject\Controllers\AdminController.cs:line 2017
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:

SqlException: The target table 'tbl_Countries' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause.
```

Here is one of the auto-generated trigger:

```
USE [myProjectDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[tr_dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17_Sender]    Script Date: 22.11.2023 00:52:59 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17_Sender] 
ON [dbo].[tbl_Countries] 
WITH EXECUTE AS SELF
AFTER insert, update, delete 
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @rowsToProcess INT
    DECLARE @currentRow INT
    DECLARE @records XML
    DECLARE @theMessageContainer NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @dmlType NVARCHAR(10)

    DECLARE @modifiedRecordsTable TABLE ([RowNumber] INT IDENTITY(1, 1), [CountryID] int, [CountryTR] nvarchar(100), [CountryEN] nvarchar(100), [CountryCode] nvarchar(2))
    DECLARE @exceptTable TABLE ([RowNumber] INT, [CountryID] int, [CountryTR] nvarchar(100), [CountryEN] nvarchar(100), [CountryCode] nvarchar(2))
    DECLARE @deletedTable TABLE ([RowNumber] INT IDENTITY(1, 1), [CountryID] int, [CountryTR] nvarchar(100), [CountryEN] nvarchar(100), [CountryCode] nvarchar(2))
    DECLARE @insertedTable TABLE ([RowNumber] INT IDENTITY(1, 1), [CountryID] int, [CountryTR] nvarchar(100), [CountryEN] nvarchar(100), [CountryCode] nvarchar(2))
    DECLARE @var1 int
    DECLARE @var2 nvarchar(100)
    DECLARE @var3 nvarchar(100)
    DECLARE @var4 nvarchar(2)

    DECLARE @conversationHandlerExists INT
    SELECT @conversationHandlerExists = COUNT(*) FROM sys.conversation_endpoints WHERE conversation_handle = '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f';
    IF @conversationHandlerExists = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @conversation_handle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
        DECLARE @schema_id INT;
        SELECT @schema_id = schema_id FROM sys.schemas WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo';

        
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tr_dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17_Sender]')) DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17_Sender];

        
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_queues WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE schema_id = @schema_id AND name = N'dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17_Sender') EXEC (N'ALTER QUEUE [dbo].[dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17_Sender] WITH ACTIVATION (STATUS = OFF)');

        
        SELECT conversation_handle INTO #Conversations FROM sys.conversation_endpoints WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE far_service LIKE N'dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17_%' ORDER BY is_initiator ASC;
        DECLARE conversation_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT conversation_handle FROM #Conversations;
        OPEN conversation_cursor;
        FETCH NEXT FROM conversation_cursor INTO @conversation_handle;
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        BEGIN
            END CONVERSATION @conversation_handle WITH CLEANUP;
            FETCH NEXT FROM conversation_cursor INTO @conversation_handle;
        END
        CLOSE conversation_cursor;
        DEALLOCATE conversation_cursor;
        DROP TABLE #Conversations;

        
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.services WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17_Receiver') DROP SERVICE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17_Receiver];
        
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.services WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17_Sender') DROP SERVICE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17_Sender];

        
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_queues WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE schema_id = @schema_id AND name = N'dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17_Receiver') DROP QUEUE [dbo].[dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17_Receiver];
        
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_queues WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE schema_id = @schema_id AND name = N'dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17_Sender') DROP QUEUE [dbo].[dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17_Sender];

        
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_contracts WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17') DROP CONTRACT [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17];
        
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_message_types WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/StartMessage/Insert') DROP MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/StartMessage/Insert];
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_message_types WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/StartMessage/Update') DROP MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/StartMessage/Update];
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_message_types WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/StartMessage/Delete') DROP MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/StartMessage/Delete];
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_message_types WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryID') DROP MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryID];
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_message_types WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryTR') DROP MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryTR];
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_message_types WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryEN') DROP MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryEN];
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_message_types WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryCode') DROP MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryCode];
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.service_message_types WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE name = N'dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/EndMessage') DROP MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/EndMessage];

        
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE schema_id = @schema_id AND name = N'dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17_QueueActivationSender') DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17_QueueActivationSender];
        RETURN
    END
    
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED)
    BEGIN
        SET @dmlType = 'Delete'
        INSERT INTO @modifiedRecordsTable SELECT [CountryID], [CountryTR], [CountryEN], [CountryCode] FROM DELETED 
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
        BEGIN
            SET @dmlType = 'Insert'
            INSERT INTO @modifiedRecordsTable SELECT [CountryID], [CountryTR], [CountryEN], [CountryCode] FROM INSERTED 
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @dmlType = 'Update';
            INSERT INTO @deletedTable SELECT [CountryID],[CountryTR],[CountryEN],[CountryCode] FROM DELETED
            INSERT INTO @insertedTable SELECT [CountryID],[CountryTR],[CountryEN],[CountryCode] FROM INSERTED
            INSERT INTO @exceptTable SELECT [RowNumber],[CountryID],[CountryTR],[CountryEN],[CountryCode] FROM @insertedTable EXCEPT SELECT [RowNumber],[CountryID],[CountryTR],[CountryEN],[CountryCode] FROM @deletedTable

            INSERT INTO @modifiedRecordsTable SELECT [CountryID],[CountryTR],[CountryEN],[CountryCode] FROM @exceptTable e 
        END
    END

    SELECT @rowsToProcess = COUNT(1) FROM @modifiedRecordsTable    

    BEGIN TRY
        WHILE @rowsToProcess > 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT  @var1 = [CountryID], @var2 = [CountryTR], @var3 = [CountryEN], @var4 = [CountryCode]
            FROM    @modifiedRecordsTable
            WHERE   [RowNumber] = @rowsToProcess
                
            IF @dmlType = 'Insert' 
            BEGIN
                ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/StartMessage/Insert] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @dmlType))

                IF @var1 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryID] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var1))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryID] (0x)
                END
                IF @var2 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryTR] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var2))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryTR] (0x)
                END
                IF @var3 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryEN] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var3))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryEN] (0x)
                END
                IF @var4 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryCode] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var4))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryCode] (0x)
                END

                ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/EndMessage] (0x)
            END
        
            IF @dmlType = 'Update'
            BEGIN
                ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/StartMessage/Update] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @dmlType))

                IF @var1 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryID] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var1))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryID] (0x)
                END
                IF @var2 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryTR] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var2))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryTR] (0x)
                END
                IF @var3 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryEN] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var3))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryEN] (0x)
                END
                IF @var4 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryCode] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var4))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryCode] (0x)
                END

                ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/EndMessage] (0x)
            END

            IF @dmlType = 'Delete'
            BEGIN
                ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/StartMessage/Delete] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @dmlType))

                IF @var1 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryID] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var1))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryID] (0x)
                END
                IF @var2 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryTR] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var2))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryTR] (0x)
                END
                IF @var3 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryEN] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var3))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryEN] (0x)
                END
                IF @var4 IS NOT NULL BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryCode] (CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @var4))
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                    ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/CountryCode] (0x)
                END

                ;SEND ON CONVERSATION '448f807c-b788-ee11-9f46-f18931e3884f' MESSAGE TYPE [dbo_tbl_Countries_a74d7aa1-fcb8-4881-ad40-6ea7b4e1af17/EndMessage] (0x)
            END

            SET @rowsToProcess = @rowsToProcess - 1
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000)
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT

        SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE()

        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState) 
    END CATCH
END
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That trigger looks like a trigger that should never exist.

Comment: For that kind of trigger to get generated "automatically", there must be some sort of monitoring or compllance package installed on that server. The trigger looks like it sends message queue messages to some other software announcing changes to the table. Ask your DBA about this. If nobody knows, open a cybersecurity ticket.  **tl;dr: WTF?**

Comment: @O.Jones I am suspicous about SignalR. It is always connected to the database to get real time data but Im not sure if it causes this problem or not.

Comment: You may be right. There's at least one [SQL Server "backplane"](https://github.com/IntelliTect/IntelliTect.AspNetCore.SignalR.SqlServer) module. It may autogenerate those triggers. The one you showed uses the message broker. Note to self: autogenerated code should always have a comment saying what package generated it.

Comment: SignalR being in the mix strongly suggests to me that it's the culprit. But! From the documentation that you linked to - "Note that doing this doesn't actually make EF Core create or manage the trigger in any way - it currently only informs EF Core that triggers are present on the table. As a result, *any trigger name can be used*, and this can also be used if an unsupported computed column is in use (regardless of triggers)." (emphasis mine). If you use an arbitrary string for the trigger name in you `HasTrigger()` call, does that get around the issue?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't automatically create triggers, especially junk triggers like that. Seems like you should be pointing the finger at [SqlTableDependency](https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency/blob/master/TableDependency.SqlClient/Resources/SqlScripts.cs).

Comment: @Ben_Thul The trigger name i used in HasTrigger() method is the same name of auto generated trigger in SQL server. The problem is sometimes current trigger disappears and a new trigger appears under my table with a new name. But content of the new trigger is always completely same with previous one

Comment: I couldn't find any solution for my problem without removing SginalR from my project and disabling broker on my database. For some reason SignalR caused that strange issue. Thanks everyone.